# How do i display different content on the same window on click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigation

Basically i have a window that has a navigation bar with different buttons on the side which are suppose to be different pages when clicked how do i make it display different content when the user is trying to navigate to a different page.

xaml code:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuOpen">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="200"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MenuClose">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="60"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btn_OpenMenu">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuOpen}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btn_CloseMenu">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuClose}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>


    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <Grid  Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF3A6E3A">
            <TextBlock Text="Rare Mantis" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock Text="More" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Foreground="White"/>
                <materialDesign:PopupBox  Margin="10" PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignRightEdges" StaysOpen="False" Foreground="White">
                    <StackPanel Width="150">
                        <Button Content="Account"/>
                        <Button Content="Settings"/>
                        <Button Content="Help"/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <Button x:Name="btn_Logout" Content="Logout" Click="btn_Logout_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </materialDesign:PopupBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="GridMenu" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FF386032">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid Height="150" Background="White">
                    <Button x:Name="btn_CloseMenu" Width="60" Height="60" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="btn_CloseMenu_Click">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowLeft" Foreground="#FF53A547" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="btn_OpenMenu" Width="60" Height="60" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="btn_OpenMenu_Click">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Menu" Foreground="#FF53A547" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListViewItem Height="60" Foreground="#FF5BF45D" >
                        <StackPanel x:Name="sp_BHome" Orientation="Horizontal" ButtonBase.Click="sp_BHome_Click">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ViewDashboard" Margin="10" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Home" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Height="60" Foreground="#FF5BF45D">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Puzzle" Margin="10" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Game" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Height="60" Foreground="#FF5BF45D">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Create" Margin="10" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Home" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Height="60" Foreground="#FF5BF45D">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Library" Margin="10" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Game Libary" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

c# back-end code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btn_Logout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}

private void btn_OpenMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btn_OpenMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    btn_CloseMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void btn_CloseMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btn_OpenMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    btn_CloseMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void sp_BHome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

So for example when `sp_BHome` is clicked it should display content that shouldn't be on other pages.

Comment: Have you read [Navigation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview)?

Comment: @Clemens im trying not to uses pages i want it to be like tab control where its all in the same window.

Comment: The most simple approach would certainly be a ContentControl where you assign different objects to its Content property. You may have different DataTemplates for each of the different object types. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added tab pages so that i can have diffrent pages on the same window.

xaml - front-end:

```
  <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="550" Margin="60,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1020" x:Name="TabControl">
            <TabItem >
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Home Page" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem >
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Games Page" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem >
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Somthing Page" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem >
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Somethiing2 Page" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

and instead of doing `ButtonBase.Click="youreventhandler"` i did `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"` to let me switch through different tab pages by clicking on `ListViewItem`.

c# - back-end:

```
  TabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before. I made a style for `TabControl` that hides the tabs at the top:

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl" x:Key="HiddenTabControl">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="cm:DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can then set the `SelectedIndex` from the code or bind it to a property in order to change the view being displayed.

This method has the added benefit of being able to see all the tabs easily in the Visual Studio designer, even though they're hidden at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem has been solved.

Comment: @WoterMelan Oh, alright. It would be good if you could post the solution you came up with and accept it so others can see that too.